# Is there a way to make comparison shorter

Tags: c#, tuples, comparison

How can I make this shorter?

```
string veryLongVariableName;

if (veryLongVariableName == "a" || veryLongVariableName == "b" || veryLongVariableName == "c"|| veryLongVariableName == "d"|| veryLongVariableName == "e"|| veryLongVariableName == "f")
```

something like this possible?

```
if (veryLongVariableName == ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))
if (veryLongVariableName == ("a" || "b" || "c" || "d" || "e" || "f"))
```

Comment: Deos [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866174/check-if-a-variable-is-in-an-ad-hoc-list-of-values) answer your question?

Answer (score 6):

You nearly had it

```
if (new [] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}.Contains(veryLongVariableName))
```

<sub>***Note*** : This does allocate every time you call it</sub>

Comment: a: should that be `Contains`, not `Any`? and b: this is pretty allocatey - fine for some things, but probably not good advice in the general case

Comment: @MarcGravell yeah it got a bit typey for 5pm on a friday, and you a right, its not the bastion of great coding. ill make a note

Comment: the allocation could be avoided by creating it as a static array somewhere, note; but... that has pros and cons

Comment: thank you for swift answers. i was too wondering if it is worth doing this for a little bit of clarity

Answer (score 2):

At risk of making your long line longer, I'd probably go with a `switch` here:

```cs
switch (veryLongVariableName)
{
    case "a:
    case "b:
    case "c:
    case "d:
    case "e:
    case "f:
        // your stuff 
        break;
}
```

(a perhaps a utility `IsSomething(...)` method that returns `true` or `false` on the condition, and just an `if (IsSomething(...)) {...}` in the code shown.

Reasons: it is clear, obvious, and efficient (no allocations; optimized by the compiler).

As an example for the `IsSomething`:

```cs
static bool IsSomething(string theThing) => theThing switch {
    "a" => true,
    "b" => true,
    "c" => true,
    "d" => true,
    "e" => true,
    "f" => true,
    _ => false,
};
// ...
if (IsSomething(veryLongVariableName)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have all your `string` conditions in a `List`, then:

```
var match = myList
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(veryLongVariableName));

if(match != null)
    //Do stuff
```

Comment: that's a *really* expensive way to write a "contains" check; that allocates a capture context and delegate every time... and I'm not even sure it does the same thing - this looks kinda like a nested (jagged) scenario?

Comment: Yes agree, but it's all depends on what the OP really want. Compiler friendly or Code tidiness.

Comment: that speaks to the "expensive" part (although I'd argue that it is *needlessly* expensive here); it doesn't speak to the "same thing" part